# Is it possible to retrieve list of Task Queues

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm wondering if it's possible to retrieve a list of defined Task Queue.

I want to create a custom page displaying the QueueStatistics (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueStatistics.html) for each queue.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002514/getting-the-tasks-in-a-google-app-engine-taskqueue

Comment: Note that I created this issue http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8405 to add this feature.

Comment: And you've had your answer by the look of it (check admin). The trouble is that *you* define the task queues and add and remove them. So I'd say that they are expecting you to also manage them and maintain your own list of active queues, as suggested in the question I linked to.